# How to use * as + named exports in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I can do:

```
import * as Name from 'module';
```

and

```
import { A, B } from 'module';
```

How to combine the 2?

```
import * as Name, { A, B } from 'module';
```

shows syntax error **expected string literal**

Comment: By combine, do you mean to AND or OR their effects? I.e. do you want to use `Name.…`, `A` and `B`, or only `Name.A` and `Name.B`?

Comment: their effects as per my non-working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot. You can only combine default import with namespace import or default import with named imports. You can however use two declarations:

```
import * as Name from 'module';
import { A, B } from 'module';
```